# What happens for DC frequency of a signal when frequency doubler is applied to a signal?

Tags: integrated-circuit, dc, frequency, signal-processing

Suppose there is a frequency doubler that doubles frequency, non-ideally. I heard that frequency doublers cannot be applied to a signal with DC bias. I really do not get what this means, so the question.

What happens for DC bias of a signal when a frequency doubler is applied? Does it spread over, or does it keep its place at zero frequency?

Comment: I have successfully designed a 30 GHz frequency doubler that needs a DC bias to work so I disagree with the statement. What happens to the DC bias depends on the circuit. DC bias = zero frequency. If it's not then it's not DC bias anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like dc frequency. We call the signal which is constant and has no changes in it's value as dc signal and it has zero frequency. The bias signal is one type of dc signal. If we take Fourier representation of a sinusoidal signal like sinusoidal signal [\$\sin(\omega t)\$], it contains the odd harmonics of the fundamental frequency. there is no dc bias present in it. If this signal is applied to frequency doubler, it's frequency would be doubled and consequently the odd harmonics are also doubled.

Now consider a signal with dc bias like \$A+B\sin(2\pi ft)\$. If we consider the Fourier representation of the signal, it contains a zero frequency component of amplitude (\$A\$) and two frequency components at (\$f\$ and \$-f\$) with amplitude (\$B\$). when this signal is applied to frequency doubler it doesn't have any effect on the zero frequency but the other two frequency components get translated to \$2f\$ and \$-2f\$.

DC bias is entirely independent of the concept of frequency doubling.

Realization of signal using transforms would help to solve the frequency related questions.Hope this answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider the basic example of an froqency multiplier which is an Diode working in **non-linear** region.

Input signal ->  m(t)= Acos(wt)

Diode Output ->  y(t)= c1 + c2* m(t) + c3*m(t)*m(t) + ..........)    :: c1, c2, c3 are constants

```
                   = K1 + k2*cos(wt) + k3*cos(2wt) +...........    ::  k1, k2 are constants
```

Now use an sharp bandpass filter centred at **2*w**  for frequency doubler.

**Effect of DC Biasing:**

Input signal -> m(t)= a + Acos(wt)

Diode output  -> y(t)= c1*(a+Acos(wt)) + c2*(a+cos(wt))^2 + ........

```
                  = X1 + X2*cos(wt) + X3*cos(2wt) + ..........      :: X1,X2 are constants
```

Again use the same sharp Bandpass filter centred at 2*w  for frequency doubler.

Now you can see that DC biasing only affect the amplitude of the output which is not a major concern in this case.